# Error while running configure when installing Ruby via RVM `C compiler cannot create executables`

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

For whatever reason, I've just imploded my RVM (which was working just fine) and tried it to install it again. I'm facing an error that prevents the installation while RVM is testing the compiler. I'd appreciate any help debugging this.

The issue occurs after running:

```
$ rvm install 2.6.2
```

of any other version of Ruby.

I get the following output

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-

2.6.2  --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
    please read /Users/andres/.rvm/log/1554329766_ruby-2.6.2/configure.log
    There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

And the configure.log shows

```
[2019-04-04 09:07:04] ./configure
current path: /Users/andres/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/andres/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/andres/bin:/Users/andres/.rvm/bin
command(5): ./configure --prefix=/Users/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/andres/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Relevant config.log lines

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2996: checking for ruby
configure:3014: found /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3027: result: /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3105: checking build system type
configure:3119: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
configure:3207: checking host system type
configure:3220: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
configure:3240: checking target system type
configure:3253: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
configure:3905: checking for C compiler version
configure:3914: gcc --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:3925: $? = 0
configure:3914: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:3925: $? = 0
configure:3914: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3925: $? = 1
configure:3914: gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang: error: no input files
configure:3925: $? = 1
configure:3945: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3967: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
ld: malformed file
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd:4:18: error: unknown enumerated scalar
platform:        zippered
                 ^~~~~~~~
 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3971: $? = 1
configure:4009: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4014: error: in `/Users/andres/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.0':
configure:4016: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Environment:

- MacOS Mojave
- Xcode fully installed with CL tools (Version 9.3 -9E145-)
- rvm 1.29.7 (latest)
- `gcc -v` outputs:

  Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
- `clang --version` outputs:

  Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

  - `xcode-select -p` outputs: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

I've tried (1) reinstalling RVM again and again. (2) Running `rvm get stable --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles` to fix any problems with bash, etc. (3) Making sure Xcode is updated. (4) Running rvm install 2.6.2 --with-gcc=clang (as suggested in some SO answers).

All these without success. I'd appreciate your help.

--- ADDITIONAL INFO ---

`gem env` output

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/andres/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/andres/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/andres/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /Users/andres/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /Users/andres/bin
     - /Users/andres/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/andres/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/andres/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: I assume you closed and restarted all terminals before reinstall RVM ?  Also can you post output of `gem env`

Comment: @lacostenycoder thanks for replying. Yes I've restarted terminals after reinstall. I'll paste `gem env` output above

Comment: looks like you multiple `/Users/andres/.rvm/bin` in your PATH.  Make sure to remove all RVM things from your .bashrc .bash_profile etc.  Then restart and try reinstall rvm. But you also have other duplicates in your PATH, this will usually cause problems.  Check where your shell is setting PATH

Comment: @lacostenycoder I see let me see re-check the bash files. When you say "Check where you sell is setting PATH" what exactly do you mean. Sorry I'm completely ignorant about working with shell

Comment: You should verify if your C-compiler can create executable

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond understanding how $PATH is set is important. Have a look at the 2nd answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/705912/where-is-my-path-variable-being-set to see where you might be duplicating, but also see https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: You might have misunderstood what I said: just check if your C-compiler is able to create executable. Use exactly the same command and source-program you see in `config.log`

Comment: @lacostenycoder thanks I’ll give that a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your xcode version is out of date. Upgrading to 10.2 should fix it.

Comment: When I go into the App Store there’s no update available for XCode, any ideas how to upgrade then?

Comment: Thanks Joel. I'll give it a try. By the way, welcome to SO

Comment: I updated Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Also, make sure you have xcode command line tools installed

`xcode-select --install`